# simple custom video player for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video, video-player

I am developing an app in which I wanna show the tutorial on how to use the app. For that need a custom video player which should look simple with a single play/pause button, a seeker and a stop button.
                    I have tried some video players like "videoplayerkit". To use this videoplayerkit I have to install cocoapods(libpods.a).  It would be very helpful if anyone help me with a custom third party video player that satisfies my need. In short I need something like this in the picture below[image]

Comment: Looks like you want `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. Not sure about the "video-cloud player" thought.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://www.engage-encore.com/index.php/2010/11/08/video-player-ipad-iphone/). This may help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I dont wanna use ios's default video player. That is why I asked for a custom one

Answer (score 0):

You can try out an example app I created if you would like to see an example of a custom movie player, the Xcode project is at [AVSync](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVSync). This movie player looks exactly like the default iOS movie player, but you can have a look at the code to see how a custom set of controls can be made to control a movie player underneath. This example sits on top on a custom movie library, but the basic idea of creating your own controls and having them submit actions is the same no matter how you implement it.