# Synchonizing Looping Video to Custom Audio

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avplayer

[WWDC2012's Real-Time Media Effects and Processing during Playback Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/517/) explains how to synchronize an `AVPlayer` with custom audio. Paraphrasing, you

1. start playback of the `AVPlayer` and custom audio at the same time
2. play both at the same rate

The first part is achieved by priming the `AVPlayer` with `prerollAtRate:completionHandler:`, so playback can be started with "minimal latency", and the second part by making the `AVPlayer` use The iOS Audio Clock.

The code snippet assumes you have calculated the future host time that *you anticipate audio hitting the speaker* (taken literally this last phrase seems to imply supreme omniscience, so let's just read it as your [desired] audio start hosttime).

```
CMClockRef audioClock = NULL;
OSStatus err = CMAudioClockCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &audioClock);
if (err == noErr) {
    [myPlayer setMasterClock:audioClock];
    [myPlayer prerollAtRate:1.0 completionHandler:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            // Calculate future host time here
            [myPlayer setRate:1.0 time:newItemTime atHostTime:hostTime];
        } else {
            // Preroll interrupted or cancelled
        }
    }];
}
```

It's a tiny amount of code, yet it raises so many questions. What happens if the preroll `currentTime` and `newItemTime` don't agree? Don't video and audio play at the same rate of one second per second? So shouldn't their clocks be the same? Doesn't 48kHz divide 60fps? How can the code only need to know the desired start time and no other details of my audio code? Is it due to the one iOS Audio Clock? Is this API ingenious or an awful non-orthogonal mish-mash that won't compose well with other AVFoundation features?

Despite my doubts, the code seems to work, but I want to **seamlessly loop** the video and custom audio. The question is how?

I can't preroll the playing `AVPlayer` because that happens from `currentTime` (and the player wouldn't appreciate having its buffers changed while playing). Maybe an alternating pair of  prerolled `AVPlayer`s? `AVPlayerLooper` sounds promising. It's not actually an `AVPlayer`, but it wraps an `AVQueuePlayer` (which is). Assuming preroll works on the `AVQueuePlayer` and I pay extra special attention to looping the custom audio, then this may work. Otherwise I think the only remaining option is to drop the prerolling and shoehorn the video and custom audio into an audio tap within an `AVComposition`, which would be looped with the help of an `AVPlayerLooper`.

Comment: So, it might be possible, but I have attempted it multiple times and I have not been able to get tight video sync and looping working with AVFoundation. The core of the issue is rapid display of video frames and it just does not seem to work. You could try out my own solution using a custom video library, it does the sync and looping but you cannot use the H264 player layers if you want it to work. Here is a SO answer with a link to the AVSync example project. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608362/763355

Comment: If you want seamless looping but you can live without tight sync on each video frame, then you might also want to examine a newer approach that does a second encoding of h.264 data so that all video data is held as keyframes and can be looped. https://github.com/mdejong/H264SeamlessLooping

Comment: It turns out you _can_ pre-roll an `AVQueuePlayer` and use it with an `AVPlayerLooper`, but sync is lost after a few loops. The audio code might have been at fault, maybe it was looping on packet instead of sample boundaries or something, but I may never find out as in the end I went with `AVComposition` + `MTAudioProcessingTap` + `AVPlayerLooper`. This way the video loops instantly and never loses sync with the audio. It was difficult to configure correctly, but that's outweighed by the fact that looping and syncing are now AVFoundation's problem and not mine :)

Comment: @MoDJ the fact that I don't understand how keyframes relate to looping video in your second link makes me think that maybe I'm misusing the word "seamlessly" here. I mean the video needs to loop instantly, without pausing to reload or buffer. For my purposes it's fine & even normal for the transition of both video and audio to be discontinuous - it just can't pause. Can you explain what you mean by seamless & why it needs keyframes? I should update my question to perhaps not use seamless.

Comment: You are using seamlessly correctly. The problem is in how long it takes to "seek" to a specific frame, this is what keyframes addresses. Please take a look at the examples to see how both implementations I referenced implement what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solutions (although I think I have succeeded in achieving tight video sync and looping with AVFoundation, so I'm not in a rush to replace AVFoundation this time:). I'm dubious about the re-encoding the whole file as I-frames seeing as the frame at time 0 should already be an I-frame (right?).

Comment: Ahh, well please publish an example of your approach on github.

Comment: The custom audio code is the problem - it's not generally useful to others and also not mine to publish. I have published a buggy audio tap sample that I need to update. It would be very easy to plug that into an `AVQueuePlayer`/`AVPlayerLooper` pair and simulate "custom audio" from a looping memory buffer. Good idea.

Comment: Fist, I did some more work on seamless looping using only AVFoundation APIs and published this on github with a couple of demos: https://github.com/mdejong/AlphaOverVideo

Comment: Cool! I look forward to trying it!